# logout issue in smarty template engine

Tags: php, authentication, smarty

I've got a small problem with my smarty project, logout problem to be precise. I have a index.php page which is the "main" page and it gets POST data and directs actions based on current data. There`s checking if the session variables has been set. Now when I login I have function like this:

```
function login($value)
{


 $res = $this->sql->checkLogin($value);         

 if($res)
 {
    //checks if user is admin
    $isadm = $this->sql->isAdm($value);

    if($isadm == true)
    {
       $_SESSION['user'] = $value['name'];
       $_SESSION['adm'] = true;
       $message = 'Admin';
       $this->tpl->assign('var', $message);
       if($_SESSION['adm'] == true)
       {
          //sets some variables for admin users
          $navigation = 'navi';
          $this->tpl->assign('navigation', $navigation);
       }
       $this->tpl->display('maint_main.tpl');
    }
    //user is not admin
    else
    {
       $_SESSION['user'] = $value['name'];
       $_SESSION['adm'] = false;
       $message = 'Perus';
       $this->tpl->assign('var', $message);
       if($_SESSION['adm'] == true)
       {
          $navigation = 'navi';
          $this->tpl->assign('navigation', $navigation);
       }
       $this->tpl->display('maint_main.tpl');
    }
 }
 //login failes, show login form and info
 else
 {
    $message = 'Login failed';
    $this->tpl->assign('var', $message);
    $this->tpl->display('login_form.tpl');
 }
 }
```

and logout function :

```
function logout()
{

 setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();
 $this->tpl->display('login_form.tpl');


}
```

These work just about the way they are supposed to but the real problem occurs when I log out and redirect to the login_form.tpl. If I use the back button of the browser the POST data with username and password is retrieved and the login goes through again. This causes that those pages behind login are still viewable. As I am not quite familiar with Smarty yet I couldn`t figure out any way to fix this. So basically how to prevent access to that POST data after logout?

Comment: Can you give us full code the login_form and logout details to understand your problem clearly?

Comment: or else if you want to use in php only then try to code it using {php}{/php} tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with smarty. This is a browser/http generic issue.  Most browsers will re-post form data after confirmation from the user.

One approach to make re-posts of the form invalid would be to pass along a secret code/token (perhaps a guid or your session id) which is also stored in session data.  When the user logs out, clear their session (or at least the secret code you're checking).  When the user logs in, check to make sure that the confirmation code matches the one for the current session.

This pattern is often used to manage csrf attacks and is often known as a 'synchronizer token'.  This blog post provides a good explanation https://blog.whitehatsec.com/tag/synchronizer-token/